# web api entity framework: return all the data whatever the query is

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Entity Framework in asp.net web api and i have a problem with IHttpActionResult, it is returning all the the database data even when i just want to get data by id.
I have a Player class, and a PlayerStat classe, each player many rows of stats according to the number of season he played.
If i try to get a Player Name, it is fine, but when i try to access player Stats, evry thing goes mad !
instead of having the player stat for each season, i get all the data in my database

```
public partial class Player
    {
        public Player()
        {
            this.PlayAt = new HashSet<PlayAt>();
            this.PlayerStat = new HashSet<PlayerStat>();
        }

        public int IDPlayer { get; set; }
        public string NamePlayer { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Height { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Weight { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateBirth { get; set; }
        public string StartPlay { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PlayAt> PlayAt { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PlayerStat> PlayerStat { get; set; }
    }

public partial class PlayerStat
{
    public int IDPlayer { get; set; }
    public string IDSeason { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string IDTeam { get; set; }
    public string Pos { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> G { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> GS { get; set; }
    /*Other Stat like GS*/

    public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
    public virtual Season Season { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

}

The request:

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetPlayer(int id)
    {
        var statsQuery = from pl in db.Player where pl.IDPlayer == id select pl.PlayerStat;

        if (statsQuery == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(statsQuery);
    }
```

Comment: imho your query is connected to the context, and the serialisation (json for exemple) fires the lazy loading....

Comment: YES! LazyLoadingEnabled = false! It worked thank you so much